# null as value in dictionary or JSON object

Tags: python, json

I need to download data from certain database where data is stored in JSON. A sample of an object that I download looks like this :

```
data =  [ 
              {
                 'field1': 'value1',
                 'field2': 'value2',
                 'field3': null
              },          
               {
                 'field1': 'value1',
                 'field2': 'value2',
                 'field3': 'value3'
              }

       ]
```

Note that for `field3`, what I receive in the `data` JSON object is not a string `null`, i.e. with single quotes wrapping it, but literally `null`. This is just the way the database server returns a data request.

When I want to work on `data` as a Python dictionary (or mashed into data frame, etc.), I get the error:

```
NameError: name 'null' is not defined
```

How would I convert all of these `null` into a string `null`, just like string `value1`, `value2`?

Further details for clarity:

This is how I obtain object `data` (by making a `requests` to a database:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd 

req = requests.get(...)
data = req.json()

print(json.dumps(data, indent=4, default=str))

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The database that I call the `requests.get()` from returns a JSON object that include `null` as value. When I print the `data` out as above, what is displayed is as above (first snippet of code).

```
print(type(data))
```

gives `<class 'dict'>`.

the last line
`df = pd.DataFrame(data)`

gives the error above.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.  You **must** provide a [mcve]. The data is not "literally `null`", `null` is a reference to some variable, which clearly is not defined. "This is just the way the database server returns a data request." You haven't provided that. What does `print(type(data))` show? What does `print(repr(data))` show?

Comment: The code you have provided tries to set `data` to be a dictionary in python but `null` has no meaning in python. The python version might use `None`. If this is `json` text you want to bring into python, `json.loads()` will convert it correctly.

Comment: You need to save 'null' instead of null when you get null from the database request. It seems like the database is in JSON witch uses null, and python uses None. It sees null and is confused.  Alternatively you can create a global object null and set it to None

Comment: "This is how I obtain object data" Did you try checking what the variable `data` contains after the `req.json()` call? Can you see what *type* of data that is?

Comment: Where exactly in this code do you get the mentioned error?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga.  I think the OP is saying that he is talking to broken server.  There shouldn't be `None` in the json, but there is anyway.

Comment: And what does `print(repr(data))` show? (I'm repeating the first comment)

Comment: @mkrieger1 This is strange. When I do ```print(repr(data)))```, all the ```null``` are replaced with ```None``` (no single quotes wrapping).

Comment: That isn't strange at all. `print(data)` should show you that result as well - assuming you actually got `data` from `req = requests.get(...); data = req.json()` as you claim. You would see `null` if you instead printed the *underlying JSON text*, e.g. if you had done `data = req.text` instead. But in this case, it would also use double quotes for all the strings, since the JSON data format does not allow single quotes for this like Python code does.

Comment: Similarly in the actual code, when you `print json.dumps(data, ...)`. That converts the parsed data in `data` back to text in the JSON format.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel You are right. ```print(json.dumps()``` gives me ```null```. However, both ```print(data)``` and ```print(repr(data))``` show ```None``` instead. I think I got the solution.

Comment: @FrankYellin It doesn't appear so. In that situation, the complaint would instead be about unexpectedly running into an ordinary `None` value while expecting to get a string value, and having a `TypeError` as a result of trying to do some string operation on it.

Comment: The server is not broken. It's just that not all fields in all objects have values. I don't know how that server work (out of my control). I just call the ```requests``` to get the data objects. And as @KarlKnechtel listed out 3 different ways to ```print```, those are how the server returns missing values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is important to be pedantic here to understand the problem. Sorry if it's a bit painful.

> The database that I call the requests.get() from returns a JSON object that include null as value.

No, it does not. The database returns bytes, which represent text, which uses the JSON format to represent a JSON object.

"a JSON object" is, *at best*, a thing that only exists in a Javascript program. It is better to think of it as an *abstraction*. We say "object" because that's what Javascript calls its dictionaries (also called "associative arrays", "mappings" and a few other things, depending on what programming language you are using, or possibly what theoretical background you're leaning on).

When you parse a JSON document (i.e.: a sequence of bytes like what the database returned) in a Python program, normally you can expect to get a native Python data structure, implemented using the built-in data types. So the top-level JSON object will be represented with a Python `dict`. JSON arrays will be represented with `list`s. Numbers will be represented with `int` and `float` as appropriate. Strings will, unsurprisingly, be `str` instances. `true` and `false` will become `True` and `False`, i.e. the two pre-defined Python boolean values.

And `null`....

> When I print the data out as above, what is displayed is as above (first snippet of code).

No, it is not. You will indeed see the display of a Python dictionary, as you show; but the way the value for the `'field3'` key is rendered, is not `null`. Instead, it is `None`.

That is because `None` is a built-in Python object that every reasonable JSON parser (including the one built into `requests`, and the standard library one) uses to represent a "null" value in JSON.

> When I want to work on data as a Python dictionary (or mashed into data frame, etc.), I get the error:

You **will not get this error** if `data` *actually* comes from parsing JSON. You will get it when you try to hard-code that Python representation of JSON into your program.

That is because the hard-coded representation should not say `null`; it should say `None`. Because that is the way that you write code to specify the value that is used in Python to represent a JSON null value.

> How would I convert all of these null into a string null, just like string value1, value2?

You *do not want to do this*. Data types are important, and exist for a reason. By using the string `'null'` to represent a null value, you lose the ability to know whether it's *really* a null value, or an actual string with a lowercase n, lowercase u etc. [This sort of thing has caused real problems for real people before](https://www.wired.com/2015/11/null/).

What you want to do is write the literal `None` in your program when you create this kind of data structure from scratch; and when you *deal* with this data - *whether you get it from parsed JSON, a hand-written structure or any other process* - look for these values by checking whether something `is None`.

---

Just for completeness:

> `print(json.dumps(data, indent=4, default=str))`

Doing this re-creates text in the JSON format which corresponds to the parsed JSON data, and displays it. So of course you will see `null` if you do this, because that is what the JSON format uses. (You will also see double quotes for all strings, because the JSON format does not allow single quotes for strings.)

Comment: I accidentally hit a key that posted while I was in the middle of typing (I'm pretty confident it was not the Enter key). I wrote quite a bit more after that. Check now.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. This is clear for me (along with other comments above).